# Item will not appear on new row using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get my div to take up the whole line, however other elements are still staying on the same line

for example, lets say I have the following:

This needs to be on one line

This need to be below the first div

I am using Bootstrap V4 for my layout,  I have not included all the code.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row title">
    <h1>Asset Dashboard</h1>
    <asp:Label ID="errorLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
  </div>
  <div class="row mainDashboard">
    <div class="col-6 box1">
      <h2>Current Assets</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 box2">
      <h2>Stock Numbers</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 box3">
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 box4">
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have attached an image of what it currently looks like.[Current Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChcRL.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default you can split a row in 12 columns.
When you say *col-6* you use 6/12. Doing that four times means that you use 24/12 available columns so the columns need to be spread in two rows.

I attached a snippet in which I divide the available space by 4 to fit in all 4 columns in one row.

[Here is a documentation of the grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row title">
      <h1>Asset Dashboard</h1>
      <asp:Label ID="errorLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="row mainDashboard">
      <div class="col-3 box1">
        <h2>Current Assets</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 box2">
        <h2>Stock Numbers</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 box3">
        <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 box4">
        <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```